# How to get Python variable annotations?

Tags: python, type-annotation

When defining a class/module with annotated fields, how can I get annotations as like in functions?

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x : int
t = Test()
```

Now I need 'int' from `getattr(t,'x')`

Comment: I am assuming you are aware of `type()`. Perhaps you could explain why doesn't that suit you.

Comment: `x` is an instance attribute. It does not exist in the class `Test` but in instances of it.

Answer (score 10):

With baseline Python, there is no option to do what you want without changing the definition of `Test`. The minimalist change would be to annotate the attribute at class level:

```
class Test:
    x: int
    def __init__(self):
        # define self.x or not, but it needn't be annotated again
```

This is actually perfectly fine; **by default, annotations at class scope are assumed to refer to *instance* attributes, not *class* attributes** (assigning to a value at class scope creates a class attribute, but annotating it does not); you have to explicitly [use `typing.ClassVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar) to indicate the annotated type is intended to be a class attribute only. [PEP 526's section on class and instance variable annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) defines these behaviors; they're something you can rely on, not just an accident of implementation.

Once you've done this, [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) will return `{'x': int}` for both `Test` and `t` in your example case.

While that's enough on its own, I'll note that in many such cases nowadays, as long as you're annotating anyway, you can simplify your code with [the `dataclasses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), getting the annotations and basic functionality defined for you with minimal typing. Simple replacement code for your case would be:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    x: int
```

While your case doesn't showcase the full feature set (it's basically just replacing `__init__` with the decorator), it's still doing more than meets the eye. In addition to defining `__init__` for you (it expects to receive an `x` argument which is annotated to be an `int`), as well as a suitable `__repr__` and `__eq__`, you can define defaults easily (just assign the default at point of annotation or for more complex or mutable cases, assign a `dataclasses.field` instead), and you can pass arguments to `dataclass` to make it produce sortable or immutable instances.

In your case, the main advantage is removing redundancy; `x` is annotated and referenced exactly once, rather than being annotated once at class level, then used (and optionally, annotated again) during initialization.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I am using dataclass, I am developing a project soon be open sourced at github. The project depends heavily on Python type hints. I currently support dataclasses but I wanted to add Python new style classes as well.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure you can get the annotations of `self.x` easily.

Assuming your code:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x: int = None

t = Test()
```

I tried looking for `__annotations__` in `Test` and `t` (where I would expect it to be), without much luck.

However, what you could do is this workaround:

```py
class Test:
    x: int
    def __init__(self):
        # annotation from here seems to be unreachable from `__annotations__`
        self.x: str

t = Test()

print(Test.__annotations__)
# {'x': <class 'int'>}
print(t.__annotations__)
# {'x': <class 'int'>}
```

---

## EDIT

If you want to be able to inspect the type of `self.x` within `mypy` check [answer from @ruohola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57079338/5218354).

---

## EDIT 2

Note that `mypy` (at least v.0.560) **does** get confused by annotating `x` both from the `class` and from the `__init__`, i.e. it looks like the annotation of `self.x` is boldly ignored:

```py
import sys

class Test:
    x: str = "0"
    def __init__(self):
        self.x: int = 1

t = Test()

print(Test.x, t.x)
# 0 1
print(Test.x is t.x)
# False

if "mypy" in sys.modules:
    reveal_type(t.x)
    # from mypyp: annotated_self.py:14: error: Revealed type is 'builtins.str'
    reveal_type(Test.x)
    # from mypy: annotated_self.py:15: error: Revealed type is 'builtins.str'

Test.x = 2
# from mypy: annotated_self.py:17: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "str")

t.x = "3"
# no complaining from `mypy`
t.x = 4
# from mypy: annotated_self.py:19: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "str")

print(Test.x, t.x)
# 2 4
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is not what I need! I just want to get annotations from fields defined within class constructor!

Comment: @Kamyar The `self.` variables are probably a glitch in the matrix (a.k.a *bug*): they are allowed by the syntax but they are not detected by `mypy` (at least within `__init__`, but they would be detected when using `t.x`), most likely because, for whatever reason, they do not trigger a corresponding `__annotations__` anywhere. Perhaps you should open an issue in Python / mypy.

Comment: There's no conflict; `x: int` is an (undefined) class attribute, while `self.x` creates an instance attribute by the same name.

Comment: @chepner that is totally correct, but `mypy` gets confused by the multiple annotation and chooses to ignore the `self.x` one.

Comment: @chepner: Actually, per [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations), `x: int` at class scope is an annotation for an (undefined) instance attribute; even `x: int = 0` at class scope means an instance attribute with a default value (though it creates a class attribute, the intent is to use it like an instance variable). Only class attributes annotated [using `typing.ClassVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar) express class attribute intent. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081373/364696) for details.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ugh, missed that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/), you can use [`reveal_type()`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html?highlight=reveal_type#displaying-the-type-of-an-expression) to check the type annotation of any expression. Note that this function is only usable when running `mypy`, and not at normal runtime.
I also use [`typing.TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING), to not get an error when running the file normally, since this special constant is only assumed to be `True` by 3rd party type checkers.

`test.py`:

```
from typing import Dict, Optional, TYPE_CHECKING


class Test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x: Optional[Dict[str, int]]


test = Test()
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(test.x)
else:
    print("not running with mypy")
```

Example when running `mypy` on it:

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:10: error: Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.dict[builtins.str, builtins.int], None]'
```

And when running it normally:

```
$ python3 test.py
not running with mypy
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to get it working while running a script from the regular interpreter?

Comment: @norok2 Unfortunately no. From the documentation of mypy: `reveal_type` *and* `reveal_locals` *are only understood by mypy and don’t exist in Python. If you try to run your program, you’ll have to remove any* `reveal_type` *and* `reveal_locals` *calls before you can run your code. Both are always available and you don’t need to import them.* I used the `sys.modules` check so that I can have the same code always, and don't need to remove anything when running the file normally.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, I thought one might work around that some other way.