# Override Python property annotation

Tags: python, inheritance, annotations

Suppose I have a base class like that one:

```
class BaseThing:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.x: Number = value
```

Then, I define a more specialized class that inherits from `BaseThing`: it does not handle any `Number`, but specifically a `Rational`.  I would like to overwrite the property's annotations, but I could not find a way to do it:

```
class RationalizedThing(BaseThing):
    x: Rational  # This is wrong: x is not a class-level property

class RationalizedThing(BaseThing):
    def __init__(self, value: Rational):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.x: Rational  # Does not change anything in my linter's point of view.  Should it?
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this. I'll note though, regarding your comment "This is wrong: x is not a class-level property": simply annotating at a class-level is actually considered an annotation for an instance attribute. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081373/3000206).

Comment: Indeed, your information answers to my question: move the annotation of `x` (in `BaseThing` as in `RationalizedThing`) in the class scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Carcigenicate and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968086/how-to-get-python-variable-annotations/57081373#57081373) said, “annotations at class scope are assumed to refer to instance attributes, not class attributes”.  So that one is valid:

```
class BaseThing:
    x: Number
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.x = value

class RationalizedThing(BaseThing):
    x: Rational
```