# Pycharm autocomplete for undefined class attributes in debug console?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

For a general Hardware class, I made optional placeholder-attributes for physical devices which might be required during runtime. This works well with autocomplete when using Pycharm's IDE. However, the debug console's autocomplete seems to know less than the IDE.

Question: Is there a way to have both defined and undefined attributes available for autocomplete in the debug console, i.e., the same behaviour as in the IDE?

Minimal example:

```py
class OptionalAttributes:
    my_string: str
    my_predefined_str: str = "hello world"
```

- **Pycharm IDE:** Both attributes and their type is available for autocomplete:

[image: IDE knows both attributes] [image: IDE knows type of undefined attribute]

- **Pycharm debug console:** Autocomplete is only aware of the predefined attribute. It does not know the attribute my_string and cannot infer its type.

[image: Debug console does not know undefined attribute]  [image: Debug console does not know the type of the attribute]

Comment: `OptionalAttributes.my_string` will lead to an error anyway, no?

Comment: @InSync Yes. Good point. I guess there is some thought flaw in the "usability" of autocomplete for unavailable attributes. I was just so used to having them in the IDE, that not having them available in the debug console occured to me as .. "wrong". But you are right, it sounds more like a feature to not show unavailable attributes during debugging, and I just got carried away by my minimal example.

Comment: The IDE doesn't have access to runtime data, so it can just guess, but the debug console does, which is likely why it only shows available attributes. If you were to assign `OptionalAttributes.my_string = 'foobar'`, you would see both attributes the next time you open the autocomplete menu (in the same session, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that variable annotation declaration does not initialize variable itself. It simply does not exist yet, so PyCharm console cannot see it.

Annotations are added in `__annotations__` of the class:

```
print(OptionalAttributes.__annotations__)
{'my_string': <class 'str'>, 'my_predefined_str': <class 'str'>}
```

More info in [PEP 526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526).

Much more detailed answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081373/22542854

Comment: Yes, it must be something along those lines. I just expected it to work the same way as the IDE. This thought was a bit to naive, I guess.